# CSS Media Queries not Working when changing resolution size of browser window

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I cant Seem to get these two queries to work together.  It seems whatever I have listed to display in the 'max-width: 1360' overrides what I have to display for 990px.  The media queries for the 990px wont overwrite anything that is defined in the 1360px queries.  I did a work around for the footer, but I don't think that is the way the system was designed.  I've done a bit of research, but I can't find anyone that is able to explain why this isn't working:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px)    {
#header {width: 990px; display: inherit;}
#header_info {width: 990px;}
#border_header {width:990px;}
#contact_data { display: none;}
#contact_data1 {width: 990px; display: inherit;}
#contact_data1 img {float: left; }
#contact_info {width: 990px;}
#wrapper {width: 990px; float: left; }
#container {width: 990px; float: left; }
#left_window {width: 200px; float: left;  }
#left_window a {font-size:20px;}
#content {width: 687px; }
#right_window {display:none}



#footer {display:none;}
#footer_content {display:none;}
#footer_container {display:none;}
#footer_content_left {display:none;}
#footer_content_center {display:none;}
#footer_content_right {display:none;}



#footer1 {width: 990px; display:inherit;}
#footer_content1 {width: 990px; display:inherit;}
#footer_container1 {width: 990px; display:inherit;}
#footer_content_left1 {width: 150px; display:inherit;}
#footer_content_center1 {width: 150px; display:inherit;}
#footer_content_right1 {width: 150px; display:inherit;}


#product_listing {margin-left: 55px; }

#breakgarage {display: inherit;}



}





@media screen and (max-width: 1360px)    {    
#footer {width: 1360px;}
#footer_content {width: 1360px;}
#footer_container {width: 1360px;}
#footer_content_left {width:330px;}
#footer_content_center {width: 330px;}
#footer_content_right {width: 330px;}

#header {width: 100%;}
#header_info {width: 1360px;}
#border_header {width:1360px;}
#contact_data {width: 1360px;}
#contact_data img {float: left;}
.contact_data_space {padding-left: 75px;}
#contact_info {width: 1360px;}
#wrapper {width: 1360px;}
#container {width: 1360px;}

contact_info img {width: 50%}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS is cascading. It is interpreted top to bottom. That's why your `1360px` styles override the `990px` styles. `990px` is a submatch of `1360px`, but it has the same priotity, so it goes down to last overrides first.

Reverse your order. If you use `max-width`, write top to bottom beginning with the biggest ending with the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your second media query to this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1360px)
```

This way it will only be applied when the screen size is between 991px and 1360px.

In your code the second media query will always be applied for screens under 990px, as something that is smaller then 990px is also smaller then 1360px, if you see what i mean...

Comment: This works too, but be aware of the fact that if you want to apply the "bigger" rules (for `1360px`) for both you would end up duplicating the styles in your code.

Comment: I appreciate that addition insight from you both.  Responsive web design is still very new to me.  I'm coming from PHP programming with intermediate Javascript knowledge.  In any event, thank you both.